# Is this a right way to check if Postgres Committed a Transaction id

Tags: java, database, postgresql, transactions, ipc

In Postgresql, If the transaction id is "123456", table name is "table1" then am I right to execute the following query? :

```
Select count (*) from table1 where xmin=123456 OR xmax=123456
```

if count returns value > 1, then can I assume that the transaction id is committed?

_

**Note:**

1. Transaction id is sent from a different java program to another java
   program via RMI (OR) TCP Sockets (OR) File (OR) some other mechanism
2. Transaction id is gathered from an after update,insert,delete
   trigger
3. Vacuum or any other maintenance procedures are not performed during these operations
4. Don't worry about txid wraparound issue either

**When using oracle, the v$transaction came to the rescue...** but in Postgres, I couldn't find anything similar...
Though some googling led me to believe there are ways to find it using the **"pg_log" file or the "pg_locks" view** but I couldn't figure out how

Only dirty way I could think of is the **xmin and xmax**... I couldn't even tell whether it's a dirty method for that matter

are there any Postgresql Sensei who can lead me in the right direction?

**Updates:**

For postgresql 9.5 and later, "laurenz albe"'s answer is perfect...
For those who use Postgresql 9.0 to 9.3, you should use,

```
SELECT count(xmin) as SIZE FROM table1 WHERE xmin = 123456 AND xmax = 0
```

Also When a Delete operation happens and you get a transaction id, we need to check it the different way...

```
SELECT count(xmin) as SIZE FROM table1 WHERE xmin = 123456 OR xmax = 123456
```

then check the result. if it returns zero, then the delete operation is committed... if result is non-zero then the transaction is rolled back and you need not worry about the uncommitted transaction

**Note:**
This is to check if the transaction id received from a trigger and sent to another external program(java) has been committed and not rolled back and the database session is different...

Comment: So you just want to know if a row with a transactionId of 123456 exists in table1 ? Why not `select count(*) from table1 where transactionId='123456'` ?

Comment: @DaveH I didn't know there is a system column named `transactionId` will it work in postgres 9.0 and 9.3 ?

Comment: Please don't add possible solutions to the question. The question should contain only information which is part of the question itself.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, oops sorry... removed it...

Comment: @DaveH, are you sure there is a system column named `transactionId` ? Coz when I checked it out in [postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-system-columns.html), I couldn't find it...

Comment: No - I misunderstood your question - I thought that you were querying an application table, not a system table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test for `xmax` is wrong.

`xmax` gets set when a row version (a *tuple* in PostgreSQL) is marked as invalid by an `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. It means that no transaction with a later transaction ID can see this tuple, and it can be reclaimed as soon as nobody can see it any more.

If a transaction is rolled back, the value of `xmax` is not reset – the transaction status is stored in the *commit log*, and the tuple remains visible to others.

But `xmax` is also used to store row locks.

So if you can see a tuple where `xmax = '123456'`, it means one of the following:

- The tuple was deleted or updated and the transaction was committed, but your transaction snapshot is older, so you still see the old tuple.
- The tuple was deleted or updated and the transaction was rolled back.
- The tuple was locked by transaction 123456, e.g. with a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

On the other hand, if you see a tuple with `xmin = '123456'` and that is not your current transaction, you can be certain that this transaction is committed.

So your test should be

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE xmin='123456';
```

But that is a **terrible** query. It forces a sequential scan over the whole table, and indexes on system columns are not allowed.

If you are using PostgreSQL 9.5 or newer, consider activating [`track_commit_timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-TRACK-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP) and using the function [`pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xid)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP). It will return NULL for transactions that are not committed.

Comment: postgresql 9.5? I'm in a bind... I'm searching for a solution 9.0 to 9.3 ... I'll mark this as answer but, this doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: is there an other solution? If not, I'll resort to the `TERRIBLE` query as you mention it... but at-least I'll have a solution... better than nothing...

Comment: I provided an alternative solution in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: appreciate your efforts... I use Postgresql 9.3 and expecting a compatibility from 9.0 that's why I decided to use the query with xmin instead of the `pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xid)` which isn't available for 9.3 let alone 9.0

Answer (score 1):

If you see the `xmin=123456` and your `txid_current() <> 123456` yes - then transaction **123456** is committed.

There's no such column as `transactionId` in postgres.

Comment: Is this the right way?... Or is there any other subtle way? or any efficient way? If so, I'll mark this as the right answer... please confirm...

Comment: in fact I already forgot about `v$transaction` as I did not use Oracle for years. And I don't recall anything alike in Postgres. to get to pg_locks you have to lock the relation and `transactionid` wont necessarily be populated. So I would say your approach looks quite reasonable

Comment: That is not correct. If you see an `xmax`, it does not imply that the transaction has been committed.

Comment: @CrystalPaladin please check out Laurenz Albe answer - I'd like you to  accept his answer instead of mine